# Extend volume where unallocated space lies ahead of it

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, diskpart

I want to extend my volume. However the unallocated space lies ahead of the volume. Is it possible to extend this volume without converting it to a dynamic volume?

[image]
<sup>[Large Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrWxF.png)</sup>

I tried to use diskpart with the extend command but it doesn't work. Makes sense because the instructions says that the unallocated space has to be behind the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Windows`s disk management surely could not extend the partition when the unallocated space is on the left of the partition, you have to use a third party partition software.

In the link below are described the steps of expanding unallocated Drive Space "From the left".

http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000678.htm